# Show cart item count and total calculated price in osCommerce template

Tags: php, oscommerce

How can I show the cart item count and total calculated price in the template_top.php file in osCommerce?

I have the following code in my template file and would like to have the numbers update as the cart does:

```
<span class="items">10 items</span>   |   <span>$500.00</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

To show the total number of items in your shopping cart, you'll want to call the following:

```
$cart->count_contents()
```

For the total cost of items in your cart, then you'll want this:

```
$cart->show_total()
```

`echo` them out as needed wherever on the template you want them to show.

In your case it would be as follows (broken across two lines for visual display here):

```
<span class="items"><?php echo $cart->count_contents() ?> items</span> | 
<span><?php echo $cart->show_total() ?></span>
```

Both of these are defined in the shopping cart class, located at: includes/classes/shopping_cart.php